# Call a function right after a figure is made visible iin Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, callback, visible

I know that every figure have a callback that is called before the figure is made visible, now i'm wondering if there is a way to call a function right after the figure is made visible, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
figure;
drawnow;
foo(); %% your function
```